# How to make a faster call for a dropdown selection

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When selecting position 200 in a dropdown it takes up to 30 seconds to return it. How can I return the result faster?

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"searchCriteria\"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select/option[221]")
private WebElement fast;
ClickControl.click(fast);
```

Comment: what do you mean by faster call ?

Comment: Its taking up to 30/40 sec to find the element, I presume the position is to blame (221) I just wanted to know if there is a way for the command to find the element within the dropdown faster.

Comment: Have you tried with `@FindBy(xpath = "(//*[@id='searchCriteria']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select/option)[221]")")`? Can you please share html or url if possible for the so that we can provide more diagnosis report.

Comment: Try css instead of xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your dropdown using Select class. Then, you can select the required value within dropdown using different methods like selectByValue, selectByVisibleText or SelectByIndex. This will surely take less time.

```
Select drpdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_your_element")));
drpdown.selectByVisibleText("abc");// selectByValue("123"),selectByIndex(1)
```